# Unity Cross Platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been thinking about this for a while. How is the unity game compiler able to compile a game for windows, mac, and linux if I'm working from a windows machine for example? For Unreal Engine for example, you need to be on the native OS in order to compile the game for it. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Java or other .NET applications, when you build a Unity project, it compiles into bytecode that runs against a virtual machine.  Unity implemented virtual machines for each target platform, and bundles the virtual machine with your game.

For some platforms, Unity can compile the virtual machine bytecode into native code.

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/06/an-introduction-to-ilcpp-internals/